# ngx-chips: adding to other input field onRemove doesn't work

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

I'm using https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips with two input fields. If a tag gets removed from the first input ("likes") it gets added to the second input ("dislikes).

This doesn't work if there is some input in the second field first.

**TS:**

```
public likes = [];
public dislikes = [];

onLikeRemove(tag) {
  this.dislikes.push(tag);
  console.log(this.dislikes);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<tag-input [ngModel]="likes" (onRemove)="onLikeRemove($event)">
</tag-input>

<tag-input [ngModel]="dislikes">
</tag-input>
```

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chips-example-5ajdec?file=app/shared/tag-input/tag-input.component.html

**Steps to reproduce**:

1) Add a tag to "dislikes"

2) Add a tag to "likes"

3) Remove the tag from likes - it should be added to dislikes, but that doesn't work.

Is this a bug in the library or am I getting something more basic wrong?

Comment: You have to push the removed item into the dislike list on onRemove() event of the likes list, it won't be doing automatically.

Comment: Am I not doing exactly that? Forgot to post my code though, just provided the demo. Updated my question.

Comment: I am not getting an editor in this stackblitz, cannot see the code

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackblitz. I updated the link, you should be able to see the code now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chips-example-5ajdec?file=app/shared/tag-input/tag-input.component.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two way binding in your code to reflect the changes on UI:

```
<tag-input [(ngModel)]="likes" (onRemove)="onLikeRemove($event)">
</tag-input>

<tag-input [(ngModel)]="dislikes">
</tag-input>
```